# why my bar chart not showing all the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, graph

I am working on a music streaming project, and I am trying to get the top15 global streamings in 2020 and make it an interactive graph.

It successfully showed the top 15 song names as a dataframe, but it failed to show as a bar graph, I wonder where did I do wrong here? Although it worked after I flip the bar graph into horizontal, but the data seem to look a bit off.

It looks like this as a vertical bar graph:
[image: Vertical bar graph]

The horizontical bar graph looks like this, but the data seem incorrect:
[image: Horizontical bar graph]

Here is the code I have:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

# load the .csv into R studio, you can do this 1 of 2 ways
#read.csv("the name of the .csv you downloaded from kaggle")
spotiify_origional <- read.csv("charts.csv")
spotiify_origional <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/info201a-au2022/project-group-1-section-aa/main/data/charts.csv")
View(spotiify_origional)
# filters down the data
# removes the track id, explicit, and duration columns
spotify_modify <- spotiify_origional %>% 
  select(name, country, date, position, streams, artists, genres = artist_genres)

#returns all the data just from 2022
#this is the data set you should you on the project
spotify_2022 <- spotify_modify %>% 
  filter(date >= "2022-01-01") %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(date)

# use write.csv() to turn the new dataset into a .csv file
write.csv(Your DataFrame,"Path to export the DataFrame\\File Name.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(spotify_2022, "/Users/oliviasapp/Documents/info201/project-group-1-section-aa/data/spotify_2022.csv" , row.names = FALSE)

# then I pushed the spotify_2022.csv to the GitHub repo
View(spotiify_origional)

spotify_2022_global <- spotify_modify %>% 
  filter(date >= "2022-01-01") %>% 
  filter(country == "global") %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(streams)
View(spotify_2022_global) 

top_15 <- spotify_2022_global[order(spotify_2022_global$streams, decreasing = TRUE), ]
top_15 <- top_15[1:15,]
top_15$streams <- as.numeric(top_15$streams)
View(top_15)  

col_chart <- ggplot(data = top_15) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = name, y = streams)) +
  ggtitle("Top 15 Songs Daily Streamed Globally") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
col_chart <- col_chart + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(999000,1000000)) + coord_flip()
col_chart
```

Thank you so much! Any suggestions will hugely help!

Comment: The chart is right. All your songs have a number of streams of approx. 100000. Hence, the small differences are simply not visible. Moreover there are two obs for "Something just like this". For this song you get two bars stacked on top of each other adding to approx 200000.

Comment: The code `col_chart <- ggplot(data = top_15) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = name, y = streams)) +
  ggtitle("Top 15 Songs Daily Streamed Globally") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))` seems to produce the right chart for me. It just isn't formatted nicely. Is the formatting the issue?

Comment: I would suggest trying something like `col_chart <- ggplot(data = top_15) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = name, y = streams)) +
  ggtitle("Top 15 Songs Daily Streamed Globally") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))`

Comment: ... also if you want to use `coord_flip` and set the limits you have to do `coord_flip(ylim = c(999000,1000000))` (and get rid of coord_cartesian).

Comment: Similar to what @stefan is suggesting, you may try something like `ggplot(data = top_15) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = name, y = streams)) +
  ggtitle("Top 15 Songs Daily Streamed Globally") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(995000,1000000))` to see more clearly the small diferences.

Comment: Forget about the existence of `coord_flip`, it's no longer necessary. Just switch your `x` and `y` aesthetic mappings for a y-axis bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
top_15 <- spotify_2022_global[order(spotify_2022_global$streams, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

This code sorts in decreasing order, but the `streams` data here is still of `character` type, so numbers like 999975 will be "higher" than 1M, which is why your data looks weird. One song had two weeks just under 1M which is why it shows up with ~2M.

If you use this instead you'll get more what you intended:

```
top_15 <- spotify_2022_global[order(as.numeric(spotify_2022_global$streams), decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

However, this is finding the highest song-weeks, not the highest songs, so in this case all 15 highest song-weeks were one song.

I'd suggest you `group_by(name)` and then summarize to get total streams by song, filter top 15, and then make `name` an ordered factor, e.g. with `forcats::fct_reorder`.